# Prevent Slim from parsing code inside <script>-tags

Tags: ruby, handlebars.js, slim-lang, ractivejs

I use `slim` for templating in a sinatra application and `ractive.js` with handlebars-like syntax on clientside.

I keep template code inside `script` tags but slim tries to parse them like the rest of the file. My simplified code looks like this:

```
section.header-section
  h1 Items
section.main-section
script#items type="text/html"
  <ul class="items">
    {{#each items}}
      <li>{{title}}</li>
    {{/each}}
  </ul>
```

For this code slim parser returns an error: `Unknown line indicator ... Line 29, Column 14 {{#each items}} ^`.

I tried the suggested workaround:

```
set :slim, {:pretty => true, :attr_list_delims => {'(' => ')', '[' => ']'}, :code_attr_delims => {'(' => ')', '[' => ']'}}
```

It didn't help. So I need `slim` to ignore everything inside `script` preserving the indentation for readability. The only possible solution is to create my own embedded engine and literaly do nothing inside it. Are there any other ways to fix it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use [`|` for verbatim text](http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/slim/frames#Verbatim_text__):

```
script#items type="text/html"
  |
    <ul class="items">
      {{#each items}}
        <li>{{title}}</li>
      {{/each}}
    </ul>
```

which produces:

```html
<script id="items" type="text/html"><ul class="items">
  {{#each items}}
    <li>{{title}}</li>
  {{/each}}
</ul></script>
```

Comment: Thank you, just what I needed!